# Create new user using Gerrit UI

Tags: gerrit

I want to add a new user/user group using gerrit web UI, however, I haven't been able to sight any way to do this. Command line would be too tedious for multiple users. Can someone tell if this is possible in the first place?
I am using gerrit 2.9.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new group here

[image]

Then, via List groups, after selecting one, you can add users to a group here

[image]

You can not create other users in the web UI, a new user has to register himself

Comment: Thanks for this. A follow up to my previous question, I am using HTTP authentication for gerrit, in that scenario, how will a user "register" himself?

Comment: A user can register with the `[register]` button on the top right corner of the web UI. By default, users are not bound to either HTTP or SSH, they can choose what authentication method they want to use and configure that in their profile settings screen. (It might be possible to configure gerrit in such a way that only HTTP is allowed, but I don't know anything about that)

Comment: @PrashantMishra are you helped?

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for the help :) Actually, [register] link is available for OPENID, and not HTTP method of authentication. For HTTP, an initial username/passwd needs to be created, using which the person can log-in and then register his email Id. Slightly different procedure, but nevertheless, it helped :) Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Tim I just had a small follow-up to my previous question. I have switched to LDAP for authentication purposes, however, what I see is, I have to manually add credentials to apacheds(ldap) server by importing a .ldif file (which also implies that there is no [register] button available for users). Is there no way to do this using some Web UI plugin?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. I tried to configure LDAP for auth once, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I've succeeded in setting up LDAP for auth, however, a few operational related things are making hurdles, like one mentioned before. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You can always ask a new question if a new problem arises